# Проблемы с подключением к vpn

Tags: linux, archlinux, manjaro

После очередной перезагрузки (раз в неделю), манджаро отказывается подключаться к vpn, говоря, что сервис то ли не запущен, то ли остановлен. Подключение PPTP. Раньше работало на ура. В чем может быть причина - не пойму. Есть сервисы как-то связанные с vpn, попробовал их повключать, но толку ноль. Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: вместо "хрен его знает" не могли бы вы продемострировать обратную связь от манджаро?

Comment: http://radikal.ru/lfp/s46.radikal.ru/i111/1610/35/374c4f3e7e00.png/htm

Comment: не могли бы вы оформить это в вопросе? тк после открытия вашей ссылки я вижу только рекламу.

Comment: Что в логах насчёт ppp/pptp?